# how to get the exact current mobile time in android?

Tags: android, time, calendar

I want to take the exact current time from the mobile and send it to the server.
But it varies near 25 mins not exactly..its varying

I could not get the correct system time

Here i have showed the code, what i have tried

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
int hr = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String date;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:mm:yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
String test = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
String months = String.valueOf(month + 1);
String days = String.valueOf(day);
String years = String.valueOf(year);
String time = hr+":"+min+":"+sec;
```

Plz help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long millis =System.currentTimeMillis;
String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));    
Log.i("Time H:M:s",hms);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
```

> Now use your rest of the code to get data

Answer (score 0):

Fetch date and time in a specific pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```